# When attaching a property or behavior, how can I access to native control behind xamarin forms elements?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Every Xamarin forms element, has a render, and every renderer has a native control behind itself.

Whenever I **develop an Attached property or behavior**, I've access to Xamarin forms element, but I've no access to native control behind that.

Is there any way to access that native control?

Note: I'm talking about built-in Xamarin forms elements such as Entry, this is not about new controls, elements and renders.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the whole point of using Xamarin Forms is to avoid dealing with native controls, and thus, to write platform-independent code. Is there a reason on why you might want to access the native control?

Comment: @UmarJamil How can you develop attached property or behavior like what this without access to native control then? <Label gestures:GesturesManager.SwipeToLeftCommand="{Binding SomeCommand}" />

Comment: @UmarJamil, no, the whole point of Xamarin.Forms is to have a framework that portably instantiates & operates the native controls.  Sometimes it is essential to access the native control, bypassing Xamarin.Forms, such as to jam in rendering changes at the platform-native level that are inhibited during Xamarin.Forms' no-rendering-permitted phase.

Comment: @optikos yeah, you're right. I've written the answer, check that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xamarin platform effects, attached properties and global styles, you can have access to all UIKit controls behind Entry tags in iOS as an example. You can apply some codes to any native control behind xamarin forms components in any platform.

https://medium.com/@ysmoradi/how-to-add-xamarin-native-platform-effect-to-all-elements-9214cf6d7b8a

Comment: To clarify for future readers, **platform-specific look-and-feel via attachment** are referred to in Xamarin Forms as **Effects**.  [Official doc for X-Forms Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/).  Effects are essentially the platform-specific equivalent of X-Forms Behaviors. They are an alternative to subclassing an X-Forms view and writing custom renderer per-platform for that view.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom control, like YourEntry, which inherits built-in Entry, with a custom renderer which inherits the EntryRenderer. There in any overridden method you can call this.Control and this.Element like this:

```
            var entry = (YourEntry)this.Element;
            this.Control.Font = UIFont.FromName(entry.FontFamily, (float)entry.FontSize);
```

this.Control is your native control and this.Element is your Xamarin.Forms control.

Comment: Whenever you're developing attached property or behavior, you're going to add some functionality to existing controls for a specific reason. Read Note section of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this article will help you with converting `Xamarin.Forms` Views into `Native` Views.
http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/

Comment: Thanks, It was very close, but I can get native controls behind layouts of Xamarin forms, but I'd like to access native control behind any kind of Xamarin forms elements.

Comment: UPDATE: This approach is probably no longer needed.  Depending on one's goal, see the other answers (Effect, or Custom Renderer+Control), or "Native Embedding" (e.g. a Xamarin Android widget within an X-Forms ContentView). Or if want the opposite, injecting a ContentPage into a primarily native (e.g. Xamarin Android) app, see "Embedding Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin Native".